# File is taking input infinitetly

Tags: c, file-io

I have following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f1, *f2, *f3;
    int number, i;

    printf("Contents of data file\n\n");

    f1=fopen("DATA", "w");

    for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &number);

        if(number==-1)
        {
            break;
        }

        putw(number,f1);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    f1=fopen("DATA","r");
    f2=fopen("ODD","w");
    f3=fopen("EVEN","w");

    while((number==getw(f1)) != EOF)
    {
        if(number%2==0)
        {
            putw(number,f3);
        }

        else
        {
            putw(number,f2);
        }
    }

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);

    f2=fopen("ODD","r");
    f2=fopen("EVEN","r");

    printf("Contents on ODD file:");
    while((number=getw(f2)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%4d", number);
    } 

    printf("Contents on EVEN file:");
    while((number=getw(f3)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%4d", number);
    }

    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);

    return 0;

}
```

This program is taking input infinitely for **FILE f1**. After pressing **-1** it should be terminated. But its not! I have pressed `CTRL+D`. But nothing happened.  I am not understanding where is the problem.

Comment: it seems to be working for me. It stops after 9 inputs and it stops earlier if I input -1. The number stored in the file are not being stored as one would want though.

Comment: The program looks good to me. Is there a reason you are using `putw`, which is not a standard function?

Comment: I am surprised that this is working also working with me. But there was two more operation that I haven't mentioned. I am editing my question.

Comment: @Scotia if your new question will be substantially different from this, it's best to post a new one. I'd recommend deleting this one if it's of no value, but not recycling it.

Comment: put "fflush(stdin)" before scanf funtion to clear keyboard buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that your call to `scanf()` will reject anything that can't be interpreted as an integer *and leave it in the input buffer*. The next time you call `scanf()`, the non-numerical character will still be there and the same thing will happen again.

[This page](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfjam.html) explains the problem in a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there would be a conversion problem, try without MINUS ONE (-1), like:

```
if(number==99)
{
   break;
}
```

or you can also try an alternative approach:

```
i=0
do {
    scanf("%d", &number);       
    putw(number,f1);
    i++
} while (i <= 10 && number != -1);
```